# Sharepoint terminology and names

Tags: sharepoint

I just want to know what is the basic structure of Sharepoint Sites?

1) What is Top level site?

2)What is Site collection?

3)What is the site Definition?

4)What is the Site Template?

5)Difference between Site Definition and Site Template.

6)What is Content Database?

7)What is the Search and indexing in the SharePoint?

8)What are Main features of sharepoint ?

Please answer one by one. I search on net lot of but, not found about proper answers of these questions.Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also like to add my own post - [SharePoint Terminology – Farms, Web Front Ends, Web Application and Sites](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/07/sharepoint-terminology-farm-web-application-site-collection-top-level-site/) - also covedrs terms like Farm, NLB, WFE, Authorization / Authentication.

[image: Web Applications - Site Collections - Top Level Site - Sites]
<sub>(source: [pentalogic.net](http://blog.pentalogic.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/Hierarchy.png))</sub>

[image: Typical SharePoint Farm topology]
<sub>(source: [pentalogic.net](http://blog.pentalogic.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/Farm-Topology.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Here goes:

1. A top level site is the rootweb of any site collection. It is generally what we think of when we create a site collection.
2. A site collection is, well, a container for sites. It always contains at least one site which can, in turn, contain zero or more sites which can, in turn, contain....
3. http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/27673
4. http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-7-All_you_ever_wanted_to_know_about_SharePoint_2007_Site_Templates.aspx
5. After reviewing 3 and 4, you'll know.
6. A content database holds all (or, at least, nearly all) the content for one or more site collections.
7. http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/data-access/making-sense-of-sharepoint-search.aspx
8. This could be tricky, since "feature" has special meaning in SharePoint, but if you're looking for business-decision-maker-level feature discussions, check out Microsoft's site: http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/Pages/default.aspx, or this good article from Joel O.: http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=267